# Finding the average rate of change of $g(x)= 10x +5$ between $x = a$ and $x = a + h$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

Trying to figure out what went wrong with the way I solved this.

So, a linear function is given. It is $g(x) = 10x + 5$ .

I know that the average rate of change of $g(x)$ between $x = a$ and $x = a + h$ is$$\frac{g(a+h) - g(a)}{(a+h) - a}.$$

I came up with$$\frac{[10(a+h) +2] - [10a + 5]}{h}.$$

I then simplified that down and came up with $20$, but apparently that is wrong?

What did I do wrong?

Edit: Ah, I forgot to say I am trying to find the average rate of change of the function between $x = a$ and $x = a + h$.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong.  $$\dfrac{(10 (a+h) + 5) - (10 a + 5)}{h} = 10$$

Comment: Note $g(a+h)=10(a+h)+5$, not $10(a+h)+2$ as you have. Still, with what you have, your simplification went awry. You should not have obtained "$20$". Try going through it again (with the proper value of $g(a+h)$, of course)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{(a+h)-a}=\frac{10a+10h+5-10a-5}{h}=\frac{10h}{h}=10$ shows that any difference quotient is $10$.

Comment: Figured what I did wrong; didn't distribute a minus sign. Simple error, thanks guy!